# Stop and Start Page Overflow / Ability to Scroll on Click

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Background:**
I created a (HTML,CSS, JS) lightbox using the tutorial [here](https://aarlangdi.blogspot.com.au/2015/01/how-to-create-lightbox-using-html5-css.html). When the lightbox overlay div is shown (when the button is clicked), I want to stop the scrollbar ability. That way, when someone is on the page looking at an image in the lightbox, they can't scroll to another part of the page. Then, when the lightbox is closed, the scrollbar ability is enabled again so they can scroll freely. I can't seem to find the right way to do that though.

I tried this:

```
$(document).css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
```

But nothing happened when I added it to my code. It was as if I never added it.

**Question:**
Is there a way to stop the page overflow ability when the lightbox is up and then re-enable it when it is closed?

Sorry if there is a simple answer. I'm new to JavaScript.

**Javascript:**

```
function startLightBox() {
  var lbBg = document.getElementById("lightBoxBg");
  var lb = document.getElementById("lightBox");
  var screenTop = $(document).scrollTop();
  var currentMid = $(document).scrollTop() + 250;

  $('#lightBoxBg').css('top', screenTop);
  $('#lightBox').css('top', currentMid);

  lbBg.style.display = "block";
  lb.style.display = "block";
}

function dismiss() {
  var lbBg = document.getElementById("lightBoxBg");
  var lb = document.getElementById("lightBox");
  var screenTop = $(document).scrollTop();
  var currentMid = $(document).scrollTop() + 250;


  $('#lightBoxBg').css('top', screenTop);
  $('#lightBox').css('top', currentMid);
  lbBg.style.display = "none";
  lb.style.display = " none";
}
```

**CSS:**

```
#lightBoxBg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: none;
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#lightBox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  display: none;
}
```

**HTML Body**

```
<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/b6JnMZL3wGs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/b6JnMZL3wGs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/b6JnMZL3wGs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/b6JnMZL3wGs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/b6JnMZL3wGs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/b6JnMZL3wGs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/b6JnMZL3wGs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/b6JnMZL3wGs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">

        <button onclick="startLightBox()">Light Box</button>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="lightBoxBg" onclick="dismiss()">

  </div>
  <div id="lightBox">
    <img src="test2.png" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

**jquery**

Use  `$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");` in `startLightBox()` function.

And use  `$("body").css("overflow", "auto");` in `dismiss()`function.

**Javascript**

Use

```
document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';  // firefox, chrome
document.body.scroll = "no"; // ie only
```

in `startLightBox()` function.

And use

```
document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';  // firefox, chrome
document.body.scroll = "no"; // ie only
```

in `dismiss()`function.

Comment: Thanks! That got me closer to a solution. I had to set document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'scroll' in the dismiss() function in order to get the scroll bar back after I closed the lightbox. Otherwise, once you click the button, the scrollbar disappears and is permanently gone (and I wanted it to be able to scroll again once the lightbox closed). If you want to change that in your answer, I'll mark it up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the overflow for the selector `html, body`, you can't directly control `document`'s css - `document` is not an element.

Here's an example:

```js
var toggled = false;
$('.visible').on('click', 'button', function() {
  toggled = !toggled;
  $(this).text((toggled ? 'Enable' : 'Disable') + ' scrolling');
  $('body, html').css('overflow', toggled ? 'hidden' : '');
});
```

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black);
  height: 140vh;
  position: relative;
}

.visible, .invisible {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
}

.visible {
  top: calc(100vh - 2rem);
}

.invisible {
  top: calc(140vh - 2rem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="visible">Visible <button>Disable scrolling</button></div>
<div class="invisible">Invisible</div>
```